# Emacs indents C++ functions in structs in an unexpected way

Tags: indentation, c++

Emacs indents functions in structs in the following way:

```
struct A {
    int a() {
        return 1;
    }

    int b()               
        {
            return 2;
        }
}

int c() {
    return 3;
}

int d()
{
    return 4;
}
```

I want `b` to be indented just like `d`. How can I fix this?

Comment: What you can do is changing the `c-default-style` variable to change indent behaviour.
the variable `c-style-alist` shows the available styles. You can check the different styles on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).

Comment: I gotta add, as a C++ veteran (and still going), that this is pretty standard indentation (add one level to inner struct methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not adding a level after opening curly braces is the default behaviour in Emacs and it's addressed in the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC#toc2) on how to avoid it:

```
(setq c-default-style "linux"
      c-basic-offset 4)
```